# can somebody show me an example of using pysimplegui not in a loop - maybe as a definition setup that I can update manually

Tags: python, progress-bar, pysimplegui

I am looking for a way to use a PYSimpleGUI progress bar... without a loop
I have looked for several days on the internet with no luck to find an example.

seems everybody does their example with a loop, or on a timer.

I'd like to do something more like a definition that I Can call to to update

I dont know what to change to make it a manually updated item...
I want to be able to tell it i=0 at teh beginning of my script
and periodically place update marks thru the script(i=i+4)
so that I can update it as each Major Step in my script is done

This is the PySimpleGUI script, plus some lines showing what I want to do
This currently auto iterates...and I do not know how to change it

I'm just trying to learn and cant find any examples online to do what I want to do.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
from time import sleep


import PySimpleGUI as sg

def prog():

    layout = [[sg.Text('Completed Tasks')],      
          [sg.ProgressBar(100, orientation='h', size=(50, 20), key='progressbar')],      
          [sg.Cancel()]]


    window = sg.Window('Progress').Layout(layout)      
    progress_bar = window.FindElement('progressbar')      

    for i in range(100):      
        event, values = window.Read(timeout=0)      
        progress_bar.UpdateBar(i + 4)
    time.sleep(2)
    window.Close()

prog()



time.sleep(2)
#______________________________________________________________

#I'd like to be able to do this

#i=0 at this point
prog()
#do Scripty Stuff

#Update Progress Bar Manually
#i=4 at this point

#do more scriptic writings

#Update Progress bar Manually
#i=8 at this point

#and so forth and so on until I reach 100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out

just leave everything as a single line, not a definition

heres an example to help others

I just did real numbers in the Update bar section
but you can use variables (i=0) and then update it in the script with an i=i+1
and then use i as your number in the update bar function

```
i=0
progress_bar.UpdateBar(i, 5) 
#i returns a value of 0

i=i+1
progress_bar.UpdateBar(i, 5) 
#i now returns a vlaue of 1

#repeat until you reach your maximum value
```

```
#this Script will create a Progress Bar
#The Progress will be Manually Updated using the format listed below
#progress_bar.UpdateBar(Value of Bar, Maximum Bar Value)
#the Window uses a .Finalize Function to make the window Persistent

#Import the PySimpleGUI Library
import PySimpleGUI as sg
#Import the Time Library for use in this script
import time

#this is for the Layout Design of the Window
layout = [[sg.Text('Custom Text')],
              [sg.ProgressBar(1, orientation='h', size=(20, 20), key='progress')],
          ]
#This Creates the Physical Window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout).Finalize()
progress_bar = window.FindElement('progress')

#This Updates the Window
#progress_bar.UpdateBar(Current Value to show, Maximum Value to show)
progress_bar.UpdateBar(0, 5)
#adding time.sleep(length in Seconds) has been used to Simulate adding your script in between Bar Updates
time.sleep(.5)

progress_bar.UpdateBar(1, 5)
time.sleep(.5)

progress_bar.UpdateBar(2, 5)
time.sleep(.5)

progress_bar.UpdateBar(3, 5)
time.sleep(.5)

progress_bar.UpdateBar(4, 5)
time.sleep(.5)

progress_bar.UpdateBar(5, 5)
time.sleep(.5)
#I paused for 3 seconds at the end to give you time to see it has completed before closing the window
time.sleep(3)

#This will Close The Window
window.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick note for everyone that is finding this answer in 2021 or later:
The `window.FindElement()` is deprecated, one uses `window.find_element()` nowadays :)

@soundtechscott: Thanks for your answer, I also encountered that issue today and your solution worked out for me.